# How to get file object in JavaScript without Event listener?

Tags: javascript

I want to get a file object in JavaScript from a html file-Input-Type without using an eventlistener. There are a Lot of exampels with eventlisteners working with the change Event but im missing an example on how to get the file with a Custom function to get the file for further Processing (websockets etc.). Does someone have a Good example?

Comment: Why don't you want to use event listeners? How else would you know when a file was selected?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Its because i handle uploads with a websocket on a different Server and i want the Form to get some other Data before and After that get the fileobject